# FrescoImageViewer - Working Example In Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, fresco

I'm very new to Android Studio and app development. I've have years of experience working with different platforms and languages, but I'm struggling to get a working example in Android Studio using the FrescoImageViewer library. How do I go about getting this from GitHub into Android Studio and have the example working?

I tried the simple Download -> Extract -> In Android Studio Go to File -> New Project -> Import Project and select the newly unzipped folder -> press OK

This results in lots of errors showing up in the code and also tells me it isn't using gradle and to migrate the project to gradle. I'm just looking to get a working example, then I can look it over and customize from there. I must be doing something wrong or missing something... sorry but I feel like this is a rookie question. I have looked a lot of places and tried many different things.

Here is the GitHub (https://github.com/stfalcon-studio/FrescoImageViewer).

Answer (score 2):

To get it in your androidstudio project, my advice is the following

in builds.gradle file, app level:

```
implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:fresco:1.9.0'
implementation 'com.github.stfalcon:frescoimageviewer:0.5.0'
```

then in your application class, method onCreate,add :

```
Fresco.initialize(this);
```

By the way, don't forget to declare your application class in your manifest

and test this simplest sample in your MainActivity:

```
String[] listimages = {"http://www.personal.psu.edu/oeo5025/jpg.jpg"}; 
new ImageViewer.Builder(MainActivity.this, listimages)
    .show();
```

I forgot, you will need this import in your activity

```
import com.stfalcon.frescoimageviewer.ImageViewer;
```